# How to access Log Panels & Perspective in Developer Console?

Tags: developer-console, debugging

While I open the Developer Console, I can see the below options under 'Debug' are disabled:

1. Switch Perspective
2. View Log Panels
3. Save Perspective

Could some one guide, how this can be enabled?

Comment: Do you have a debug log open in dev console (and is the log the current thing being displayed in dev console)?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Switch Perspective will only be available when we open a log in the console. After you open a log you can do it.

For Save Perspective I am providing you this link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_perspectives_creating.htm&type=5

For View Log Panels I am providing you this link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_view_system_log.htm&type=5

Apart from these here is a trailhead link that might help you out: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/developer_console

Hope these helps you.